# What does the armor compensation skill do?

Tags: eve-online

> EM Armor Compensation
>
> To active armor hardeners: 3% bonus
>   per skill level to Armor EM resistance
>   when the modules are not active To
>   passive armor hardeners: 5% bonus per
>   skill level to Armor EM resistance.

would that mean that an active hardner gives 0.03*0.55 = 1.65% resistance if its not active? or rather just give 3% resistance if you have them but not use them?

and for the passive ones, is this a bonus like 20%res * 1.05 => 21%res for your armor?

the descriptions got me confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While *inactive*, **active hardeners** receive a 300 [basis point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_point) boost to their resistance stat, so at level 1 they will provide 3%, level 2: 6%, level 3: 9%, and so on (it seems like going from 0 to 1 only gives you a 200 bp bonus).  The compensation skills do nothing while the module is active (as the skill says).

**Passive hardeners** (resistance plating) receive a relative 5% boost per skill level, so with T1 plating it will be a total boost of 20% * 5% = 1% per skill level.

Comment: seems i was right there. thanks for clearing it up.